# Codeigniter user form errors not showing

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my codeigniter login. If user types in incorrect user name it should display error saying **Username or Password Incorrect** as flash-data. And if user puts in username that does not **exist** then would throw error **Username Not Match Any Records**.

Cannot get the form database check errors to display correct way. I can login OK but just not throwing login flash-data errors correct.

How can I get my form database errors to work correct. The main codeigniter form validation are OK just not throwing my database errors.

```
public function index() {

      $this->load->library('form_validation');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

      if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

          $this->login();

      } else {

         if ($this->input->post('username') && $this->input->post('password')) {

            // Gets the user information from the database. 

            $user = $this->user_login_model->get('username', $this->input->post('username'));

            if ($user) {

             // If User Login Success

               if ($this->user_login_model->check_password($this->input->post('password'), $user['password']) == TRUE) {

                  $this->user->login($user['user_id']);

                  redirect('admin/dashboard');

               } else {

                  $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Username or Password Is Does Not Match Any Records!');
                  $this->login();

               } 
            }
         }
      }
   }

  public function login() {
  $this->document->setTitle($this->lang->line('heading_title'));

    $data['text_login'] = $this->lang->line('text_login');
    $data['text_register'] = $this->lang->line('text_register');

    $data['entry_username'] = $this->lang->line('entry_username');
   $data['entry_password'] = $this->lang->line('entry_password');

    $data['action'] = site_url('admin');

    $data['button_login'] = $this->lang->line('button_login');

    return $this->load->view('common/login', $data);
  }
```

Get User model

```
/**
   * Retrieve a user
   * 
   * @param string where
   * @param int value
   * @param string user_identification field
   */
   public function get($where, $value = FALSE) {
      if (!$value) {
         $value = $where;
         $where = 'user_id';
      }

      $user = $this->db->where($where, $value)->get($this->table)->row_array();
      return $user;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flashdata will only be shown if the user is redirected to another page. 
On the failed login action you only load a view to the user's screen. Try altering

> $this->login();

to

> redirect('controller/login'); //ofc change the controller name first

Comment: I tried that the problem I am having was not showing correct errors where should be. Shows blank page when enter user name that does not exist and no error showing

Comment: @acoderslife By your description I can understand that you may have a problem in your model where you select the user and return the result to the controller. Can you add your login model as well to your question? A blank page may be a php error or something that doesn't have to do with your login function in the controller.

Comment: Added model get function to post

Comment: Found solution where if($user) close bracket } is added `else { $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'No user exists please check again'); redirect('admin'); }` works now

Comment: @acoderslife Flashdata is working now because you are redirecting the user to another page, as I prompted you on my reply :).

Comment: It is same page just named admin in routes